# Can someone please explain this housing prices equation?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, housing

Can someone please explain to me the following formula from this [paper](https://sites.wustl.edu/rodymanuelli/files/2018/01/GMP_01_20_2018_RM-11zc3w0.pdf) ? It's on the end of page 16 and the beginning of page 17.

I don't know if it is asking too much, but I am looking at these equations for hours now and can't figure out what the underlined parts mean or why they are there. I am grateful for any kind of help.

[image: Formula 1][image: Formula 2]

Comment: The subscripts are partial derivatives with respect to the subscript, so $u_{c} = \frac{ \partial u(\cdot) } {\partial c}$, and $1$ is... 1?